# Retrieving data from API using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, canvasjs

I'm trying to build a dynamic chart that updates every second off of this API data using CanvasJS: http://www.coincap.io/history/1day/BTC

I can't get the correct values to show. Right now it is only showing the first data set (MktCap) in the X axis. I need the data from the second set (Price). Am I messing up the keys?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var dataPoints = [];
    var chart;
    $.getJSON("http://www.coincap.io/history/1day/BTC", function(data) {  
        $.each(data, function(key, value){
            dataPoints.push({x: value[1][0], y: parseInt(value[1][1])});
        });
        chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
            title:{
                text:"Live Chart with dataPoints from External JSON"
            },
            data: [{
                type: "line",
                dataPoints : dataPoints,
            }]
        });
        chart.render();
        updateChart();
    });
    function updateChart() {
    $.getJSON("http://www.coincap.io/history/1day/BTC", function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            dataPoints.push({
            x: parseInt(value[1][0]),
            y: parseInt(value[1][1])
            });
        });
        chart.render();
        setTimeout(function(){updateChart()}, 1000);
    });
    }
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in `$.each(data, ...` because `data` is an object, with the following shape:

```
{
  "market_cap": [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], ...],
  "price": [[0, 21], [1, 42], [2, 11], ...],
  "volume": [[0, 10], [1, 3], [2, 2], ...],
}
```

When calling `$.each` over the object, it is iterating over the keys of the object. With you code, it is getting only two items of the array. What you would want to do is choose `"price"`, so it will iterate over all of the items. For example:

```
$.each(data.price, function(key, value) {
  dataPoints.push({
    x: value[0],
    y: value[1],
  })
})
```

Both in the initial and `updateChart` functions. Please note that you don't need to use `parseInt` because it is already an integer. After that, you will see the correct line.

Comment: Thanks! It is working now. The only issue I'm having is the value[0] is being displayed as miliseconds in the chart. Is there a way to convert it to a date string (like "12-May") without needing to add a function?

Comment: Not sure about CanvasJS. Unless you use a third party library like momentjs (very useful), you could do it with just JavaScript but it will take a few lines. Please take a look into: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp . Basically, you want create a new date: `new Date(value)` and the call `.getMonth()` and `.getDay()`. You will need to have an array of the months strings

Comment: Are you looking for `xValueType: "dateTime"`[https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/data/xvaluetype/]